# jQuery - hide / show divs when checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

I have a jquery function to show or hide divs when certain checkboxes are checked or unchecked and work fine using the "change" function. Therefore, if the checkbox has already been previously checked the corresponding div is not shown. How can I change this code to work?

My code is here:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('.my_features').change(function() {
            var checkbox = $(this);                 
            if( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {                       
                $( '#' + checkbox.attr('data-name') ).show();
            } else {                      
                $( '#' + checkbox.attr('data-name') ).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Change `change` to `click`

Comment: The result was the same with "click" ...

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty canonical.

I would use data-id instead of data-name though:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.my_features').on("change",function() { 
    $(`#${this.dataset.id}`).toggle(this.checked);
 }).change(); // trigger the change
});
```

```css
.toggleDiv { display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="my_features" data-id="div1">Div 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checked class="my_features" data-id="div2">Div 2</label>
<div id="div1" class="toggleDiv">Div1 div</div>
<div id="div2" class="toggleDiv">Div2 div</div>
```

If you do not like mixing DOM and jQuery access then

```
$(`#${$(this).data('id')}`).toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
```

Comment: I'm about to answer this approach. You are faster few seconds. Haha +1

Comment: Great answer, it worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your question was how to show/hide the divs for checkboxes that are already checked/unchecked upon loading the page.

You can do this by passing in the same function you are using for `change()` into the `each()` method, which will iterate over each checkbox and run the function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.my_features').each(function(){
    var checkbox = $(this);
    //you can use data() method to get data-* attributes
    var name = checkbox.data('name');
    if( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {                       
      $( '#' + name ).show();
    } else {                      
      $( '#' + name ).hide();
    }          
  });
});
```

Demo

```js
function update(){
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var name = checkbox.data('name');
  if( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {   
    $( '#' + name ).show();
  } else {                      
    $( '#' + name ).hide();
  }          
}

//just setup change and each to use the same function
$('.my_features').change(update).each(update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="my_features" type="checkbox" data-name="first" />
  <input class="my_features" type="checkbox" data-name="second" checked />
  <input class="my_features" type="checkbox" data-name="third" checked />
  <input class="my_features" type="checkbox" data-name="fourth" />
</div>

<div id="first">First</div>
<div id="second">Second</div>
<div id="third">Third</div>
<div id="fourth">Fourth</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! The mplungjan solution worked best for me, but I found your answer to the problem quite interesting. I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to get the data and then show or hide the div based on the checkbox value

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.my_features').on('click', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var div = checkbox.data('name');

    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
      $('#' + div).show();
    } else {
      $('#' + div).hide();
    }
  });

})
```

You can see a working [**`fiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/buttflattery/t4z5cdum/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.my_features').change(function(){
            if(this.checked)
                $('#data-name').hide();
            else
                $('#data-name').show();

        });
    });
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this way.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.my_features').each(function() {

        $(this).change(function() {

        var checkbox =  $(this);         
        if( checkbox.is(':checked') ) {                       
            $( '#' + checkbox.attr('data-name') ).show();
        } else {                      
            $( '#' + checkbox.attr('data-name') ).hide();
        }
    });
    });
});
```